# How can I fix the issue: "Unable to connect to the database" while using npm run start?

Tags: nestjs

I'm [following](https://github.com/invzbl3/rest-api-nestjs) the next [article](https://medium.com/swlh/create-an-api-rest-with-nestjs-1954723e8234) and on the step while I'm running the command as:

```
$ npm run start:dev
```

I'm getting constantly the issue as:

```
[Nest] 27096  - 12/30/2022, 9:21:27 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (5)...
MissingDriverError: Wrong driver: "undefined" given. Supported drivers are: "aurora-mysql", "aurora-postgres", "better-sqlite3", "capacitor", "cockroachdb", "cordova", "expo", "mariadb", "mongodb", "mssql", "mysql", "nativescript", "oracle", "postgres", "react-native", "sap", "sqlite", "sqljs", "spanner".
    at DriverFactory.create (C:\Users\invzbl3\WebstormProjects\rest-api-nestjs\src\driver\DriverFactory.ts:72:23)
    at new DataSource (C:\Users\invzbl3\WebstormProjects\rest-api-nestjs\src\data-source\DataSource.ts:139:43)
    at createTypeormDataSource (C:\Users\invzbl3\WebstormProjects\rest-api-nestjs\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm-core.module.js:172:23)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\invzbl3\WebstormProjects\rest-api-nestjs\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm-core.module.js:176:46)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\invzbl3\WebstormProjects\rest-api-nestjs\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm-core.module.js:20:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\invzbl3\WebstormProjects\rest-api-nestjs\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm-core.module.js:16:12)
    at C:\Users\invzbl3\WebstormProjects\rest-api-nestjs\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm-core.module.js:174:76
    at Observable._subscribe (C:\Users\invzbl3\WebstormProjects\rest-api-nestjs\node_modules\rxjs\src\internal\observable\defer.ts:55:15)
```

I put *two* files in the project, as there was mentioned:

1. `ormconfig.js`:
   https://github.com/invzbl3/rest-api-nestjs/blob/main/ormconfig.js
2. `.env`:
   https://github.com/invzbl3/rest-api-nestjs/blob/main/.env

Based on it, my question is:

am I missing something? Do I need to add something here? If yes, what do I need speficially to do here to beat this issue?

**UPD**:

I have changed the format of `DB_URL` instead:

```
DB_URL=postgres:dbUser:dbPassword@localhost:5444/dataBaseName
```

to:

```
DB_URL=postgres://dbUser:dbPassword@localhost:5444/dataBaseName
```

The issue is still here.

Thank you in advance for any smart ideas here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are missing the correct format for the database scheme, your `.env` file should have the following format: `DB_URL=postgres://dbUser:dbPassword@localhost:5444/dataBaseName`. Notice the `://` it is the same as `https://` in URLs, just for databases :).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, [vl4d1m1r4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/976509/vl4d1m1r4). I've [done](https://github.com/invzbl3/rest-api-nestjs/commit/0e39f5e705e4f875e16feb59fa174fc0c912c651) it, but it didn't help me. Could you clarify, please, do I need to use any specific commands before running `npm run start:dev`? If yes, what should I run then?

Comment: Is there a different error now?

Comment: No, I'm still getting: `ERROR: [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database.`. I suppose I need to run something before executing it or I'm missing some configs.

Comment: Yes, but do you still get the MissingDriverError? Also check if the local postgres db is started and you use the same user and password for starting the database and in the .env file.

Comment: Yes, I'm still getting [MissingDriverError](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/f6108c5be0f1cb1ebea5b6869fd8d9e8#file-stacktrace-L7). Thank you for pointing out about local postgres db. I'll re-check it now.

Comment: Okay, I've restarted via `pg admin` the local postgres db server with own `login` and `password`. Created there `dataBaseName`. Updated with these `login` and `password` file `.env` accordingly, but the error still the same. It's still confusing me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I cloned the repo and tried it myself, and yes I get the same error. What I was able to find out is that `ormconfig.js` is not read at all and also the environment variables are somehow asnyc loaded in the framework. But, if you hard-code the values in the `app.module.ts` in the `forRoot()` method of TypeORM, you will be able to connect to the database. I have never used this Nest js thing, but if you want to do it proper way I would start here: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

Comment: Thank you for the article:
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration
I have found the cause of issue. I needed to change instead:
`imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(), UserModule]`
to:
`imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot()]`, but I'm struggling with the issue while executing the `POST` query:
`"statusCode": 404` with `"message": "Cannot POST /users".`